# using Date.today in joins part of named scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

For some reason, the Date class is recognized when I use in the where

```
scope :with_active_subthing, joins("left outer join thing_subthing on thing_subthing.patient_id = thing.id").where("thing_subthing.start_date <= ? AND ( thing_subthing.end_date > ? OR thing_subthing.end_date IS NULL ) ", Date.today, Date.today)
```

but doesn't recognize it when I use it in joins

```
scope :with_active_subthing, joins("left outer join thing_subthing on thing_subthing.patient_id = thing.id AND (thing_subthing.start_date <= ? AND ( thing_subthing.end_date > ? OR thing_subthing.end_date IS NULL )) ", Date.today, Date.today)
```

I get:

```
RuntimeError: unknown class: Date
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the [underlying code that builds the join portion](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f67944e7579711e2c28ea8b48ec739c1ff1966ae/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L333-L347), you can see that it is looking for specific object types, and Date is not one of them. The error is sort of confusing, but what it's saying is that a Date cannot be used as an argument for `joins`. It's not really clear from your question why you want to do this, but you should absolutely be using both joins and where together as you've done in your first example.

Here's the code that is causing the issue because it's falling through to the "raise" line:

```
def build_joins(manager, joins)
  buckets = joins.group_by do |join|
    case join
    when String
      'string_join'
    when Hash, Symbol, Array
      'association_join'
    when ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency::JoinAssociation
      'stashed_join'
    when Arel::Nodes::Join
      'join_node'
    else
      raise 'unknown class: %s' % join.class.name
    end
  end
```

Comment: accha.  I see.  I see.

The problem with using the where clause though is that it effectively turns it into an inner join

What I ended up doing is just using now() in the SQL, which makes it less database agnostic, but got it done.

Comment: Just got back to a proper computer.  So the code I used was basically:

Comment: scope :with_active_subthing, joins("left outer join thing_subthing on thing_subthing.thing_id = thing.id AND (thing_subthing.start_date <= now() AND ( thing_subthing.end_date > now() OR thing_subthing.end_date IS NULL )) ")

So anyways, reason why I want the conditions on the join itself is I want the query to return the each thing and, if they have a subthing that is active (which not all subthings are) return their active subthing (active meaning today is between their start and end date.)  Those same conditionals in the where clause would exclude all the things without subthings.

Comment: @BrandonHamilton it's not really clear at this point what your question is. Your original question seemed to be asking why you were an error about the unrecognized Date class, which I answered. If you have other questions about how to do the query better, I would open another question and make it clear what you are asking so it will get more answers.

Comment: You are totally right.  You answered the post as it was asked, and it was helpful in arriving at a practical solution.  The bit about the query is a bit extraneous and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @BrandonHamilton - did you follow this up with a question elsewhere? Could you link to it.